# Mysql confusion with priority of order by

Tags: mysql, sql, case, sql-order-by

I am beginner in sql and this is the mysql code I was testing.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INT,
    nm VARCHAR(16),
    occ VARCHAR(16)
);

INSERT INTO test (id, nm, occ)
VALUES (1, "E", "X"), (2, "B", "X"), (3, "C", "Y"), (4, "D", "Z"), (5, "A", "Z");

SET @r1 = 0, @r2 = 0, @r3 = 0;

SELECT *,
CASE WHEN occ = 'X' THEN (@r1 := @r1 + 1)
     WHEN occ = 'Y' THEN (@r2 := @r2 + 1)
     WHEN occ = 'Z' THEN (@r3 := @r3 + 1) END AS rownumber,
CASE WHEN occ = 'X' THEN nm END AS X,
CASE WHEN occ = 'Y' THEN nm END AS Y,
CASE WHEN occ = 'Z' THEN nm END AS Z
FROM test
ORDER BY nm;
```

My question is as follows. If I remove the `ORDER BY nm` clause what I get is this table below:[image]

But if I add the clause I get the following table:

[image]

Why is the rownumber 1 in the row with `nm = 'A'` in the second table after applying `ORDER BY nm`? I would think it is 2 because I thought `SELECT` takes precedence over `ORDER BY`.

Comment: `ORDER BY` is the last operation performed, so you get the same results as the first table, but sorted by the `nm` column. You may need to `SELECT` from a subquery that orders the results before populating the `rownumber` column.

Comment: You are probably after [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) and `ROW_NUMBER()` as a function.

Comment: Don't use variables (`@` sign). They are deprecated and supported in MySQL 5.7; this version of MySQL is reaching end of life in 13 months from now.

Comment: It is that way, because that is how you are calculating the rownumber.  What is the purpose of the rownumber

Answer (score 3):

This question has been asked before. [You can check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql), so then maybe can help you to understand it.

I can help you to read what the meaning of the rownumber from your code. First, let's understand what's the total value of each rownumber.

```
SELECT occ, count(occ) FROM test GROUP BY occ ORDER BY occ;
```

This is another code from your first result

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY occ) AS rownumber, 
CASE WHEN occ = 'X' THEN nm END AS X, 
CASE WHEN occ = 'Y' THEN nm END AS Y, 
CASE WHEN occ = 'Z' THEN nm END AS Z FROM test;
```

And this is how will I show you your two results CMIIW. You can compare the row number for each `nm` value with `occ` value.
When nm is `E` then `X` first appears in the first result, it's 1 so then nm `B` has rownumber is 2. Unlike from the second result, when nm is `B` then `X` first appears its 1 so then nm `E` with `X` has rownumber is 2.

There is has another function to get row number in MYSQL but it's just for `MySQL 8.0 or later`. You can read for `ROW_NUMBER() function` [here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/) and `RANK() function` [here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-rank-function/).